# Generic predicate in Java 8

Tags: java

## Use Case

Creating a generic and reusable predicate with closures that supports Float, Double, Integer, float, double, and integer.

### Problem

Extending "Number" doesn't allow for the modulo operator.

#### Code

Below is the form I'd like the code to be. However, Number doesn't support the modulo function.

```
public <T extends Number> Predicate<T> isDivisibleBy(T divisor) {
    return (T dividend) -> dividend % divisor == 0;
}
```

### Current Solution

The current solution I have uses method overloading, but just doesn't seem DRY. How can I improve this code?

```
public Predicate<Integer> isDivisibleBy(Integer divisor) {
    return dividend -> dividend % divisor == 0;
}

public Predicate<Float> isDivisibleBy(Float divisor) {
    return dividend -> dividend % divisor == 0;
}

public Predicate<Double> isDivisibleBy(Double divisor) {
    return dividend -> dividend % divisor == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `Number` doesn't provide any methods to check for divisibility directly, it does provide a method to make the `Number` into a `double`, and as we all know, doubles *do* support the `%` operator.

Other slight modifications:

- Your method can be static
- You don't need to specify the `(T dividend) ->`, simply using `dividend ->` is enough.

Final:

```
public static <T extends Number> Predicate<T> isDivisibleBy(T divisor) {
    return dividend -> dividend.doubleValue() % divisor.doubleValue() == 0;
}
```

I have tested this code for many cases using a for-loop, and it works mostly fine.

I had one problem with using `Long` though as the `Long value = -195798407404780179L` was converted into `-1.95798407404780192E17`, which loses some accuracy. So it seems like you need a special case for `Long`:

```
public static Predicate<Long> isDivisibleBy(Long divisor) {
    return dividend -> dividend % divisor == 0;
}
```

However, be aware that there are *some* primitive variants available for `Predicate`:

- `IntPredicate`
- `LongPredicate`
- `DoublePredicate`

Comment: Probably worth doing specials for `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` too as their `doubleValue` is rarely likely to exhibit similar `%` maths to the original.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Absolutely, didn't think about the fact that `BigDecimal` also extends `Number`. I don't think one for `BigInteger` is necessary though since that is covered by `BigDecimal` I believe.